# Ubuntu 20.04. When I boot my OS it gets stuck on this screen with lines and green ok on the left

Tags: boot

Tried booting and looking for errors in recovery mode, but didn't find anything and got this screen again.
Would really appreciate help.

Picture of the black screen:
https://imgur.com/eb8cPDE

Comment: Nothing wrong with anything in the image.